# Create a list using the letters in x

Tags: python, list

Using list comprehension, create a list of all the letters used in x.

```
x = ‘December 11, 2018’
```

I tried writing each letter out but I am receiving a syntax error!

Comment: Please include your code and the full error message.

Comment: Please include your code and the exact traceback you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

In Python a string acts as a list; it is easier and quicker to convert the list into a set (only unique values) and then back to a list:

```
unique_x = list(set(x))
```

Or if you must use list comprehension:

```
used = set()
all_x = "December 11, 2018"
unique_x = [x for x in all_x if x not in used and (used.add(x) or True)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "December 11, 2018"
lst = [letter for letter in x]

print(lst)                       # test
```

Output:

> ```
> ['D', 'e', 'c', 'e', 'm', 'b', 'e', 'r', ' ', '1', '1', ',', ' ', '2', '0', '1', '8']
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list comprehension like:

```
x = ‘December 11, 2018’

new_list = [letter for letter in x]

print(new_list) 

# Output
# ['D', 'e', 'c', 'e', 'm', 'b', 'e', 'r', ' ', '1', '1', ',', ' ', '2', '0', '1', '8']
```

Alternatively, you could skip the list comprehension and just use `new_list = list(x)` to get the same result.

if you want only the letters and no spaces, you can use .replace on x like: `x.replace(' ','')` or add on if clause in your list comprehension:

```
new_list = [letter for letter in x if letter != ' ']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```py
x = list('December 11, 2018')
print(x)
result = []
for item in x:
    try:
        int(item)
    except ValueError:
        if item == "," or item == " ":
            pass
        else:
            result.append(item)

print(result)

"""
Output:
['D', 'e', 'c', 'e', 'm', 'b', 'e', 'r']
"""
```

If you are using only dates with that format, you could do this

```py
x = "December 11, 2018".split()
print(x[0])
"""
Output:
'December'
"""
```